# Handling multiple pressed keys with KeyListeners

Tags: java, keyboard, control, callbacks

I'm making a game Applet with Java that uses `KeyListener`s to control a paddle (for a game like Breakout/Pong). My basic implementation goes like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            direction = "LEFT";
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            //repeat for the rest
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        direciton = "";//paddle doesn't move
}
```

My problem is that when the user tries to change the direction of the paddle twice too fast (let's say you press *left*, then *right* and *left* again super fast), the paddle freezes for a split second, and continues to move along its direction.

I understand that the problem is the logic in my code, but I can't think of a better implementation. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs **state**.

At the moment, this is what happens if you press *Left*, press *Right*, then release *Left*:

```
-> keyPressed(left):  direction = "LEFT";
-> keyPressed(right): direction = "RIGHT";
-> keyReleased(left): direction = "";
```

The paddle doesn't move, even though *Right* is still pressed!

You can solve this by checking in `keyReleased` if the opposite direction is still down and reset the direction to `""` only if it isn't.

Unfortunately, since `KeyListener`s only tell you when keys go down and up, not whether they are down at the moment. You [must track this state yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846164/how-do-you-get-the-current-keyboard-state-globally-i-e-what-keys-are-currentl). You can do it by setting variables `leftIsDown` and `rightIsDown` in the `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` cases for each key.

Answer (score 0):

... A more expensive way:

```
public class TimerExample implements KeyListener {
private Timer right;
private Timer left;
private Timer down;
private Timer up;
public void defineTimers() {
    ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Move LEFT
        }
    };
    right = new Timer(10, l);
    ActionListener r = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Move RIGHT
        }
    };
    right = new Timer(10, r);
    ActionListener d = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Mode DOWN
        }
    };
    down = new Timer(10, d);
    ActionListener u = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Move UP
        }
    };
    up = new Timer(10, u);
}

    @Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        up.start();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        down.start();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        right.start();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        left.start();
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        up.stop();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        down.stop();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        right.stop();
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        left.stop();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to gamedev.se! Could you add some explanation of what the code is doing and why it solves the issue at hand? Poorly documented blocks of code are not as helpful as well explained ones.

Answer (score 0):

States can be achieved with enums, I'm writing a similar game too and thanks to @Anko I implemented his solution like this:

```
public enum PaddleWay {
    UP, DOWN, STOP
}
```

---

```
private void handleMovement(){
    if(p1paddleway == PaddleWay.STOP) {
        paddle1yPos = paddle1yPos;
    }
    if(p1paddleway == PaddleWay.UP) {
        paddle1yPos -= PADDLESPEED;
    }
    if(p1paddleway == PaddleWay.DOWN) {
        paddle1yPos += PADDLESPEED;
    }
    if(p2paddleway == PaddleWay.STOP) {
        paddle2yPos = paddle2yPos;
    }
    if(p2paddleway == PaddleWay.UP) {
        paddle2yPos -= PADDLESPEED;
    }
    if(p2paddleway == PaddleWay.DOWN) {
        paddle2yPos += PADDLESPEED;
    }
}

    @Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
    //p1 inputs
    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
        p1paddleway = PaddleWay.UP;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_Z:
        p1paddleway = PaddleWay.DOWN;
        break;
    //p2 inputs
    case KeyEvent.VK_O:
        p2paddleway = PaddleWay.UP;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_K:
        p2paddleway = PaddleWay.DOWN;
        break;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
    //p1 inputs
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:
            p1paddleway = PaddleWay.STOP;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_Z:
            p1paddleway = PaddleWay.STOP;
            break;
    //p2 inputs
        case KeyEvent.VK_O:
            p2paddleway = PaddleWay.STOP;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_K:
            p2paddleway = PaddleWay.STOP;
            break;
    }
```

It's a little long but you can just copy paste once you write one method and simply manipulate.